# Css Autoprefixer for multiple files in single function/go ?

Tags: css, angular, autoprefixer

My Angular2 project having 100+ Css files, those files does't have any prefixer like for :Mozila, :Chrome etc, i want some tool or any gulp task or anything which will convert my all css files into files having prefixers.

I have tried this

> https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

but not working as per my use case,

so is it possible ? if yes how ?

Comment: It's more of a Linux question than an angular question I think.

Comment: may i know how Linux question ? yeah its not much related to angular

Comment: Linux or Windows sorry, it's a file system task to rename your files. Try googling `Windows/Linux rename multiple files`

Comment: i am not talking about renaming multiple files, instead i'm talking about autoprefixer's of css, i think you have to google it before ;) never mind

Comment: Ooooooh I see, sorry I misunderstood ! You can use your IDE to do that. What do you use ?

Comment: no problem mate, IDE how ? i am using sublime as well as VS Code, i think using IDE its too much lengthy process and time consuming too, with lot of bugs

Comment: Well it's your only fast option ... You do a Ctrl+Maj+F, and you use a regex to find all your props, such as `^\s*([a-z\-]*\s*):(\s[^;]);$` and replace it with your mozilla prefixes like `moz-$1: $2;`

Comment: can you add all the process as answer ? i did't get your point here, seems your comment may be useful . and what `maj` here in ctrl+MAJ+F

Comment: Done, see it below !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for an answer :

In your IDE (I take Visual Studio Code as an example):

- Ctrl+Maj+F will launch the global search (or on the left toolbar, click on the magnifying glass)
- Activate the "search by regex" option (represented by a `.*`)
- Enter your regex. It goes like this

  `^\s*([a-z-]*)\s*:\s*([\d\w-()"\s\.:=!@]*);?\s*$`
- In the second field, use something like

  `moz-$1: $2;\nsafari-$1: $2;`

It will add "moz-" to every property found by the regex.

Of course I typed it fast, so you will have to make some adjustements, but the idea is here.

**EDIT AFTER CHAT** Here is the explanation :

- It starts with a ^, meaning "the line starts here"
- then \s* means "line starts with as much tabs or space you want"
- ([a-z-]*) means "find properties that contain a to z letters, and - characters"
- \s* just as above, some spaces
- the : for the : in every css property
- again, \s*
- ([\d\w-()"\s.:=!@]*) means "find the property value that contains letters, numbers, spaces, and every special charachter listed (.:=!@)"
- then we close the line with a ; (appearing zero or once)
- then as much space as you want with \s*
- and $ means the end of the line (contrary to ^ at the start)

To answer how it's possible : when you put parenthesis in a regex, it "captures" what it finds and register it in a variable starting with a $ sign. That's why you write $1, $2 in the replace string, because it captured the property name, and the property value. The \n allows a line return, and all you have to do is put as many prefixes as you want like that !

Comment: this does nothing , first of all may i know what is function of this regex ? bcoz after applying no result found

Comment: Do you know how to write a regex ?

Comment: i wrote as you mentioned in the answer, global search and than copy paste this regex

Comment: I wrote that you need to make some adjustements ... So my question is, do you know how to write a regex, or should I write one for you ?

Comment: ohh, no i dont make any adjustments, please Update your answer

Comment: Ok try this new one, it should get all the css properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145028/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 1):

There is a node.js tool called Autoprefixer, which does exactly what you need. PostCSS autoprefixer is actually only a wrapper around it. You can use it directly.

If you don't use Gulp, Grunt or some other task runner, you can use Autoprefixer manually from command line.

First install it:

```
npm install -g autoprefixer
```

Then use it on some file:

```
autoprefixer file.css
```

Or on multiple files:

```
autoprefixer -d processed *.css
```

Comment: have you read my question ? i already mentioned that i am using this autoprefixer but not working as expected

Comment: @PardeepJain Well, you asked how to use autoprefixer on multiple files at once. I answered that in second example... If autoprefixer doesn't work, I guess it is better idea to fix it and make it work instead of manually prefixing ALL properties (since only small part of them really needs prefixing and some of them have completely different syntax that you can't handle just with regexp, ie. flexbox). Autoprefixer manages all of that for you.

Comment: yess i agree with you regex can't do this trick every time, btw thanks for answer, let me try your method too